Ctrl, Shift and Alt keys not working in linux mint 21.3
This may sound weird, but all my shortcut keys aren't working! When ever I use Shift+MMB, it acts as if I'm hitting MMB only!
The shortcut keys are working perfectly when I use them outside of blender, but when I use it inside blender it just doesn't register!
I am using Linux Mint 21.3 and this problem started happening a week ago. I have tried switching kernels, but that doesn't do anything!
Thank you.
Sincerely,
xomnion.
